# Font size does not affect value 0.1 to 0.4 em

Tags: html, css

I have control that helps user can change font size themself. But font size on html does not affect when size value is from 0.1 to 0.4 em. I am using Google Chrome Version 27.0.1453.110 m

HTML

```
<span class="text_menu_link">Home</span>
```

CSS

```
span.text_menu_link {font-size: 0.3em;}
```

Comment: There is a [minimum font size](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/1999Mar/0086.html) in every browser. If you want to override that, you may take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2421056/how-can-i-override-the-minimum-font-size-in-firefox).

Comment: Care to elaborate on browers you are testing in? Works fine in safari 6.0 on OSX10.8 see: http://jsfiddle.net/JcrXw/ for test code

Comment: @Antony, minimum font size setting does not prevent the effect of the setting; it just restricts its effect so that you don’t get below the limit set.

Comment: Not reproducible. Do you actually mean that the font size *is* affected by the `font-size` setting but the size reduction is smaller than you expect? Please be specific: what is your basic font size setting, and what is the size of the font in the element for which you set `font-size: 0.3em`, and what is the effect if you change the value to, say, `0.7em`?

Comment: @Jukka: Here is the source code http://jsfiddle.net/dQZcF/ . Each item has a different font size, but they look the same except the last item

Comment: @HV again this is browser dependant it your code works as is in firefox. With releative font sizes it isn't abad idea to set a base point. You could set this on `body`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`em` is a relative font size. If you put your example inside another div that has a large font-size set, you'll notice that you *do* see a change at the 0.1 - 0.4em range, because it evaluates to a reasonable actual font size (above the browser's minimum).

HTML

```
<div class=outer>
<span class="text_menu_link">Home</span>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.outer {font-size: 30pt;}
span.text_menu_link {font-size: 0.3em;}
```

See [this](http://jsfiddle.net/nJkQz/1/) for an example

**Edit**

[An example setting `font-size` at the body level](http://jsfiddle.net/nJkQz/2/)

Comment: you may also mentioned your fiddle link inside `this`, it's looks good and not stretch your code too much.

Comment: I disagree as to which looks better... but it's not important. I'm sure it's a distinction that's been debated on meta.

Comment: @jcsanyi: Thanks for your answer. Is there any way to make it works without div containing it? Because I only set font-size in em for .outer or not using it for my case.

Comment: I would recommend not using `em` for font-size unless you've defined an exact font size for an outer container. `em` is like percentage... so if you don't specifiy an exact fontsize that you're taking a percentage of, you're basing your site on whatever the user's browser defaults to. Try using `pt` instead.

Comment: in releation to @jcsanyi comment above, you can always set the base  font size on the `body` or `html` tag.

Answer (score 1):

From the sample code provided via jsfiddle in a comment, the question appears to be “why do some font size settings have the same effect” rather than no effect:

```
<div>
<span style="font-size: 0.1em;">Home</span>
<span style="font-size: 0.2em;">Home</span>
<span style="font-size: 0.3em;">Home</span>
<span style="font-size: 0.4em;">Home</span>
<span style="font-size: 0.5em;">Home</span>
</div>
```

These have an effect, as you can see by comparing them with the display of a plain “Home”. They just have the *same* effect, in many situations, and the reason is that there is a **minimum font size** setting in the browser.

With a typical basic font size of 16 pixels (12 points), the setting `font-size: 0.5em` asks for a size of 8 pixels. That’s larger than a typical minimum font size of 11 pixels, so 11 pixels will be used. And for the other settings in the example, the result is of course the same.

If you change, in Chrome settings, the minimum font size to 6 pixels (smallest that it seems to allow, and far too small for almost any purpose), you will notice that the last “Home” becomes larger than the others – since it is now the requested size 8 pixels, whereas `0.4em` requests for 6.4 pixels, so the end result is hardly distinguishable from that of 6 pixels that will be used for the other texts due to the limit. Besides, Chrome seems to actually round 6.4 to 6 here (judging from what it shows in developer tools).

And if you add, say,

```
div { font-size: 120px }
```

you will see that the words will all have different font sizes.

Finally, if you set the font size of the `div` e.g. to the same as the minimum font size of the browser, then the `font-size` settings indeed have no effect.