# Inconsistent spacing in different browsers

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

I need to create a simple calendar design. The problem is, that I cannot change the HTML markup, which is created from a PHP script. The calendar is created as an unordered list, where each **li**-tag represents one day.

From left to right, these are *Google Chrome*, *Mozilla Firefox* and *Internet Explorer*:

[image: Google Chrome]
[image: Mozilla Firefox]
[image: Internet Explorer]

I want each of them to look like the Chrome-example (I will remove the unnecessary border to the right afterwards). I have tried a lot of things to solve this, a negative margin for instance - Which of course changed the look in Chrome. According to [this article](http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/) it is caused by spaces, tabs and linebreaks between the **li**-tags, which is only half the truth.

I figured out, that the creating script returns the list without any spaces in between. This however is only true for the days, not the heading - Don't ask why, I don't know either... See the code below for an example.

```
<li class="day first">Mo</li>
<li class="day">Tu</li>
<li class="day">We</li>
<li class="day">Th</li>
<li class="day">Fr</li>
<li class="day">Sa</li>
<li class="day">Su</li><li class="first outofrange">&nbsp;</li><li class="outofrange">&nbsp;</li><li class="outofrange">&nbsp;</li><li class="outofrange">&nbsp;</li><li class="outofrange">&nbsp;</li><li class="outofrange">&nbsp;</li><li class="past">1</li><li class="first past">2</li><li class="past">3</li><li class="past">4</li><li class="past">5</li><li class="past">6</li><li class="past">7</li><li class="past">8</li><li class="first past">9</li><li class="past">10</li><li class="past">11</li><li class="past">12</li><li class="past">13</li><li class="past">14</li><li class="past">15</li><li class="first past">16</li><li class="past">17</li><li class="past">18</li><li class="past">19</li><li class="past">20</li><li class="past">21</li><li class="past">22</li><li class="first past">23</li><li class="past">24</li><li class="past">25</li><li class="today">26</li><li class="future">27</li><li class="future">28</li><li class="future">29</li><li class="first">30</li><li class="outofrange">&nbsp;</li><li class="outofrange">&nbsp;</li><li class="outofrange">&nbsp;</li><li class="outofrange">&nbsp;</li><li class="outofrange">&nbsp;</li><li class="outofrange">&nbsp;</li></ul></div></div>
```

---

[image: Mozilla Firefox, Take two]

This is the second Firefox example, without the space between the days. As you can see, it solved the problem, but as there's still space between the heading, it's not perfect. It doesn't work for Internet Explorer however, no matter whether I have spaces or not, it still has the offset between each element.

Here's a [JSFiddle-Exampe](http://jsfiddle.net/SqU3F/1/) of my code. *Remember, I cannot change the HTML markup!*

I hope you can help me to make them look consistent.

Comment: Well, you still have spaces between your heading items... What you're leaning here is the main reason people (like me) stick to `<table>` - it may not be semantically accurate, but damn it it works!

Comment: Try adding `font-size:0px;` to the `calenderio` class

Comment: @Anzeo Some browsers have a "minimum font size override" setting.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol I completely agree with you, I would have also used a table for this. But as I said, I have no option to change the HTML markup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can't change the html at all, one solution would be to **use floats** instead of inline-block elements so that the margin between all elements doesn't depend on font-size or spaces in the html markup.

I tested this **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/SqU3F/2/)** in the latest versions of IE, FF and chrome and they have the same rendering.

```
.calendario ul li {
    float:left;
    list-style-type:none;
    ...
}
```

To prevent layout issues, you also need to clear the floats. In the demo I use a pseudo selector on the `<ul>` element :

```
.calendario ul:after{
    content:'';
    display:block;
    clear:both;
}
```

Comment: I can't tell why I haven't thought of this earlier... I changed the li's to `display: block;` prior to floating them and it works like a charm on every of my tested browsers. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Padarom Glad you found a solution. BTW the default display property of `li` element is block so you shouldn't have to specify it.

Comment: I haven't forgotten to use your `list-style-type:none;`. Apparently explicitly specifying a `li` as a block-element does the same thing. But I'll replace it, thanks for mentioning.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to resort to a `<table>` unless you were to be warped back into time and somehow ended up in the 90ies.

The issue you're having here is caused by displaying elements `inline`. It does not matter whether it's `inline-block` or not. You could compare elements that are displayed inline as words, and as with words there are spaces between them.

A simple solution is to set the font-size of your containing element to 0 and then override this in the elements where you want to display text. You have already set the font-size for these latter elements, so you could solve this simply by adding

```
font-size: 0px;
```

To the `calenderio` class.

Edit: In case the browser sets a minimum font size (which IMHO is plain stupid), you can solve this by checking the accepted answer on [this other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2421056/how-can-i-override-the-minimum-font-size-in-firefox). It's a hack for a buggy implementation of the browsers, but should you encounter issues with setting font-size to 0, then at least you could patch the browsers behaviour.

Comment: As I mentioned in reply to your posting this as a comment, some browsers have a "minimum font size override" setting, which is intended to ensure that the user can read text on the page - for instance, someone who is visually impaired may set this setting to, say `14pt` to get all webpages in large print. This will, for lack of a better term, "bugger up" your solution.

Answer (score 0):

You still have spaces between your list items for the headings. Remove those too.

That said, you can maintain some vestige of reasonable layout of your source code with this trick:

```
<li class="day first">Mo</li
><li class="day">Tu</li
><li class="day">We</li
> ...
```

Notice how I'm putting the whitespace *inside* the closing tag? This is perfectly valid (if a bit unorthodox) and allows you to "have no space on the page" *and* "have readable HTML" at the same time!

EDIT: If JavaScript is an option, try this:

```
function stripWhitespace(node)
{
    // note: only applies to first-level children, not descendants
    var n = node.childNodes, l = n.length, i;
    for( i = l-1; i >= 0; i--)
    { // work in reverse because `childNodes` is live
        if( n[i].nodeType == 3 && n[i].nodeValue.replace(/\s/g,'') == "")
        {
            node.removeChild(n[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Call that function and pass it your `<ul>` element. The spaces between `<li>`s will be removed.

Comment: While this fixes it in Firefox, the problem remains in IE (I need to account for that too). Also, I can not change the markup

Comment: Oooo, I've never known this before... Niiiiice!

Comment: @Padarom Strictly speaking, you should be minifying your HTML before sending it to the browser. I have some PHP magic code stuff (read: hax) that strips out all newlines and tabs that are not inside a `<textarea>` or any element with `white-space` CSS making the spaces meaningful. This also solves all my spacing problems, while keeping legible source code.

Comment: @Anzeo When fixing styling issues *with constraints on the HTML source*, JavaScript may be considered as a suitable option.